# Question regarding serial in serial out shift register

Tags: shift-register

I started learning serial in serial out shift register today as below picture.

[image]

I have a question but can't search the reason behind on internet. As an example, when input "110" is connected to a serial in serial out shift register with 3 block below, it need extra 2 random bit "XX110" to get the 110 output right? If this the case, then why not only use 1 block? Isn't it will directly get the output result of "110" without the need of extra bit? Don't really understand the purpose of shift register, what the point of adding more block to it?

Comment: You should not need two extra random bits. Why not give us full details how to replicate your project, including which shift register you use, how you have connected it and to where, and if there is some program code sending the bits.

Comment: You don't need any block. You can connect the output directly to input to get '110'. Not sure what's your objective.

Comment: Sorry should have attached the link of the youtube channel on shift register explanation. The instructor shown in that example it will required extra 2 bits to get the output but if we use lesser block, we don't need that extra bit to get "110" output right? So why need to use extra block?

Comment: @chackt I bet very few people are interested in watching a video to know what you are asking. Please make your question standalone. Shift registers do not need extra clocks. If you have a serial in parallel out shift register of 3 bits, it needs 3 clocks to get all 3 bits clocked in to the respective 3 output flipflops.

Comment: Alright my bad, I try to simplify it

Comment: After you clock in the first bit of 3, the serial output is still undefined, i.e. "X". Only after 3 clocks will you see the first bit "1".  At which point the other 2 bits of your sequence are stored inside the register and not visible on the output yet. How do you expect to get them out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Serial in, Serial Out, yes, they are first in, first out devices.  The oldest bits are clocked out.

There are a number of advantages.  Usually *all the bits* are available on their own output lines, in parallel, even for serial in, serial out devices.

Also, when you stop clocking, the bits stay where they are, serving as rudimentary memory.

Comment: Thanks, I did not see the main point earlier is to keep the memory when the clock stop as you mentioned.